# Question regarding Intermediate fields and the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Consider the splitting field of the irreducible polynomial $x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $K = \mathbb{Q}(\omega,\theta)$ where $\omega$ is the cube root of $1$ and $\theta = (2)^{1/3}$. Why isn't the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\theta^2)$ in the correspondence diagram shown here? Since, $ \mathbb{Q}(\theta^2) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.
[image: Text]

From:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory

Comment: $(\theta^2)^2=2\cdot\theta$, and so $\mathbb{Q}(\theta^2)=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. So it appears in the diagram.

Comment: Mark's comment is the simplest way to cure your confusion. For another: $[\Bbb{Q}(\theta):\Bbb{Q}]=3$, a prime number, so the tower law prohibits the existence of an intermediate field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you for that comment, will use it to check my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Here $\theta$ and $\theta^2$ are both primitive 3rd roots of unity with $\Bbb Q(\theta) = \Bbb Q(\theta^2)$.

Comment: $\theta=\sqrt[3]{2}$...